# Skip "this$0" field during field iteration in Spring ReflectionUtils

Tags: java, spring, reflection

I'm using Spring ReflectionUtils to iterate over all fields of a class. The problem is that the target class is an inner class, so it contains "invisible" reference to the parent class called "this$0". And I'm wondering: what is the proper way to skip such field, because I don't want to process it? I think filtering by name (`name.startsWith("this$") || name.startsWith("super$")`) is a bad approach, so I hope there's a better solution (still it's used there: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/reflection/CachedClass.java).